# If globals are bad, why does every web framework use them?

Tags: global-variables

Every web development framework I've come across, including the best designed ones (Web2Py, Kohana) make use of some form of global variables to represent objects that are global within the application domain- for example, objects representing 'request' and 'response'.

On the other hand, the idea that global variables are bad is one of the fundamental axioms of programming. Indeed the now common disparagements of the singleton pattern usually point to the fact that it's nothing more than globals in disguise, as if that were explanation enough.

I'm trying to understand once and for all how globals can be so condemnable and at the same time be a seemingly indispensable part of all our web frameworks?

Comment: The problem is possibly that unqualified statements like "global variables are bad" are an oversimplification.

Comment: There are lots of other reasons that overuse of singletons is bad. For example, they don't play well with unit testing.

Comment: At some level there is a *global value* in any language, however this is hidden or abstracted (or not). The bigger issue, IMOHO, is *mutable global state* and *fixed un-mockable types*.

Comment: I've never heard that particular complaint about Singleton and it strikes me as somewhat hollow. The Singleton pattern ensures that an object actually exists, is created only once, and that all internal components use the same object. In other words, it avoids several problems that could be thought of as reasons why global variables are bad in the first place.

Comment: @ShiggityShiggityShwa No, it doesn't: a singleton is a stable identifier in most languages and thus *not* easily amendable to testing/mocking (of course, this varies by language and there is DI, etc.) The only thing a singleton necessarily does this case is act as a "lazy initialized immutable variable", which does not get around the other issues with global variables.

Comment: I don't recall saying it avoided ALL of the problems with global variables.

Comment: @Oli- agreed, but that's how it's usually [presented](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=globals+are+bad).

Answer (score 6):

What is a global? Taking your text I assume you mean a variable that's declared at global scope. Such variable could be overridden by any assignment and break existing functionality.

However, in OO languages, everything is inside a class and assignment can be wrapped in gettors and settors for properties, or completely hidden behind methods. This gives a safe way of dealing with globals. Note that in proper OO languages (Java, C#, VB.NET etc) it is **not possible to have global variables** (sometimes a language construct suggests otherwise, but static fields in C# or modules in VB, mixins in Ruby are all wrapped in classes and thus not truly global).

A singleton, you mention it, is a special kind of global. As a designer you can control how many instances run of it. A car only needs one engine, a country only one government (or war breaks loose) and a program needs only one main thread. **Globals are a necessity to programming, the real discussion should not be, do we need them, but how to solidly create and use them.**

You say that request and response objects are globals in web development. They are not. They are (usually, depending on your toolset) convenience variables set in scope before your code is run. Since a web application can have multiple request objects at any given time, I think these are a poor example of a global variable. They are not (but they are usually local and a singleton to your current thread).

One important feature that you cannot cover in traditional procedural languages (like Basic, Pascal, C) is access control and thus concurrency and thread safety for global variables. In .NET for instance, any static method or property in the BCL (one could say that any static variable is global by definition) is thread-safe by design. Guidelines for user-defined static methods or properties suggest you do the same.

EDIT: the danger is with languages that allow global variables but at the same time propagate themselves as truly OO. While these are wonderful languages, it is indeed dangerous to step out of the protection of OO and create globals in for instance Perl, Python, Ruby, PHP.

Comment: @Abel- thanks, some good thoughts. I'm trying to understand your reasoning on 'request/response' not being global. Clearly they're not global across multiple requests, but your description of them as being 'singletons to your current thread' is in fact what I mean when I talk about globals. e.g. when register_globals is turned on in PHP, that scope is still within a single thread? I'm not sure whether I'm getting tripped up by semantics or concepts here- can you expand on that at all?

Comment: @Yarin: you didn't specify a language so I answered as language-agnostic as I could. You use PHP. PHP _can_ use global vars (but this is discouraged). If you turn globals on in PHP (bad idea) it does _not_ make globals thread-safe (rather the reverse: globals are inherently not thread-safe). About request/response objects in PHP: this may depend on your system, installed libs etc. IIRC, you don't have Response.Write in PHP, but echo and print instead (and yes, it can be debated whether that's good design, but hey, it's lossy PHP ;).

Comment: I'm looking for language-agnostic answers. Let me try this a different way: In Python/PHP/.. if a variable is not scoped within a function or class, it is considered to be in global scope. I'm also lumping singletons and statics into this bucket I call global. It's this context I refer to when I say I see both legitimate widespread [use](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/4#request) and widespread [condemnation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx). I appreciate your explanations so far, but I'm still trying to understand the distinction.

Comment: @Yarin: let me try (and, when you see this and I'm still online, we can continue in Chat). Variables in global scope are bad. They can be overridden without a compiler error. Whether these are singletons, statics (they all are static in a way) doesn't matter. Yes, there's widespread use. Wherever you find them, replace them with a class, say Util or Global, and create proper accessors to them. In most cases, global vars should become read-only, initiate-once properties of a class. This protects them from re-assignment and makes your code more readable, maintainable and reliable.

Comment: Finally, some languages don't support classes, like most functional (Haskell, F#), logic (Prolog) and procedural (C, Basic, Pascal). Some of these do and some don't support global vars. Whatever the case, best practice dictates that you should wrap any access to global vars in a (generic) wrapper, like `GetState<T>(EnumState)`, with a global enum or list of constants. This way, you hide the globals behind a function and you can still control creation and access.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly in what context those globals are used in web frameworks, but anything global starts to create problems as soon as you need to have solid access control. If you start to use such a global in concurrently executing program, it's quite hard to say who and when accessed and changed it. It creates so-called shared state. This makes debugging even more difficult.

Anyway, I am not really in favour of such statements. This only leads to oversimplifications. You have to weight you requirements and then decide if this or that pattern brings more positive or negative effects...

Comment: What if the global variable is immutable?

Comment: Well, if the global is immutable, then it's somehow constant and np. With thread-local stuff... well... that's sort of language-dependent right? Anyway, threads are obsoleted, use Erlang, Scala, Clojure or something... ;-)